# Uso de contas marionetes

Tags: debate, suporte, contas-usuário, stackoverflow

Galera, eu tinha essa conta no **stack overflow pt** porém não usava muito, tanto que voltei a usar ontem, só porque na minha conta principal eu fui acusado de usar contas marionetes, mas lá está como se eu tivesse nessa conta aqui quando eu entro no chat saca? E aqui eu levei ban de 30 dias, lá foi de um ano sendo que essa conta não tem nada a ver, lá é minha principal, e alguém pode me ajudar no que fazer ?

Gostaria de entrar em contato com os moderadores que está investigando meu caso, por que não consegui entrar em contato com eles nem da minha conta principal nem por está, tentei pelo chat e por email e não consegui, e poxa, lá eu já tinha 400 e pouco de reputação, agora estou com 1, apesar que ganhei mais depois do ban por bônus de associação mas continuou em 1, eu nem tinha levado ban na conta principal, era pra ter sido 30 dias ou um pouco mais, não é justo, e vocês podem ver na minha outra conta que eu dei respostas corretas, só fiz 3 perguntas e estavam boa, eu contribui para o stack overflow, alguém me dá uma luz pelo amor de Deus?

**Obs:** Não consigo falar com os moderadores, só consegui falar com o Guilherme Nascimento e não deu certo porque ele não estava investigando meu caso

Comment: O META é apenas para discussão sobre o funcionamento do site. Problemas individuais devem ser tratados pelo formulário de contato ou como respostas às mensages de moderação. Sobre o "Gostaria de entrar em contato com os moderadores que está investigando meu caso," não é algo necessário. Toda equipe de moderação tem acesso à situação dos usuários dos sites onde modera.

Comment: A conversa dos comments ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119582/discussion-on-question-by-dakota-uso-de-contas-marionetes), quem tiver algo a acrescentar ou quiser ler, pode usar o link fornecido.